# jQuery Ajax response header returns empty string from Echonest request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spotify

I am making **Ajax** request with **jQuery** to **Echonest**, as you might know Echonest returns some headers to see the rate limit. I tried everything I know to read headers but I couldn't get any header.

This is my code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({traditional:true, cache: false});
                    url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key=' + api_key + '&callback=?';
                    var req = $.getJSON(url,
                        {
                            id : songID,
                            format: 'jsonp',
                            bucket:['audio_summary']
                        }).done(function(data, status, resp){

                           console.log(resp.getAllResponseHeaders())
                           console.log(resp.getResponseHeader('X-Ratelimit-Limit'))
                        });
```

And this is the screenshot of the response:

[image]

I am trying to read **X-Ratelimit-Limit**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to get headers from a jsonp request, but that service looks like json so do a json request instead.

Comment: Good to know, I didn't know that. I will check now.